# Inserting Values into MySQL DB using NodeJS Not Working

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, digital-ocean

Currently I am experiencing a very frustrating issue with inserting data into my MySQL db using my NodeJS Express server.

My current setup is the following:
• MySQL server db on DigitalOcean droplet.
• NodeJS Express server on the same DigitalOcean droplet. It is being proxied by my Apache server that is on the same droplet. I keep Node server running with PM2.

I have been able to successfully read data from my db (i.e. `SELECT * from performance);`).
However, no matter what I try I cannot insert any data into my db. I have tried countless different solutions but none have worked.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Please ask any questions for further clarification if needed. Thank you.

My current code relating to MySQL:

**server.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'analytics',
    supportBigNumbers: true,
    debug: true,
});

server.post('/performance', (req, res) => {
    let d = req.body;
    con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        let q =
            'INSERT INTO performance (uid, reqStart, resEnd, loadDuration) VALUES ?';
        let values = []; // values to be inserted into db

        // for testing purposes I have commented this out and tried inserting a hardcoded set of values instead
        /*let body = JSON.parse(req.body); // json string body to json obj
        body.data.forEach((x) => {
            values.push([body.uid, x.reqStart, x.resEnd, x.loadDuration]);
        });*/

        values = [
            [23299730, 8.3282343284, 8.121252244, 2.238932989],
            [23288734, 8.3282343284, 8.121292244, 2.238932989],
        ];

        con.query(q, [values], function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    });
    res.send(d);
});
```

**Update**: I just ran my server manually (without PM2). This has allowed me to view console messages. For the first time I have seen a successful insert query. And upon running the server with PM2 I also get a successful query. However, on the second attempt I get `PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_HANDSHAKE_TWICE` error.

Based on multiple other posts/articles I thought my code avoided this problem, but it's erroring on the line where I call con.connect(...). I have con.connect in a server.get route, but I haven't been hitting that endpoint at all.

Comment: Have a look at sequelize.org. It is a much better idea to use an ORM rather than writing your own queries.

Comment: Please share the error message

Comment: Thanks @recoilnetworks, I will look into that.

And Ramaraja, that's part of the problem. As far as I can tell there is no error when running the insert query. Is there somewhere I should be looking to make sure there is no error?

Comment: I have just updated my post with some info. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of debugging, I think I found the problem.

Almost all tutorials showing how to connect to MySQL db using Node show that you should embed a `con.query()` call within a `con.connect()` call, and using `connect()` is recommended on MySQL docs.

However, `con.query()` also establishes a connection. Maybe it's because I am keeping the server live across multiple calls, but this results in the Handshake error I described in the post. Removing the wrapping `con.connect()` call fixed my problem.